# mysqli create a foreign key in reference to a primary key doesnt work

Tags: php, mysqli, foreign-keys

Hey I am trying to make a guestobook with two tables. First table is for: the users (User_ID[primary key], Name, Mail, Password) and the second table is for the comments: (Comment_ID [foreign key], Message, Date).

Now I am trying to reference from User_ID to Comment_ID. But I am getting the Error: No Database selected.

```html
$db           = "dbname";
$tblGuestbookUsr = "tblGuestbookUsr";
$tblGuestobookComment = "tblGuestobookComment";

// parent tbl
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$db`.`$tblGuestbookUsr` 
( `Usr_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`Name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL , 
`Mail` TEXT NOT NULL , 
`Password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`Usr_ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Succes <br />";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn). "<br />";
}

// child tbl
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$db`.`$tblGuestobookComment` ( 
`Comment_ID` INT NOT NULL , 
`Nachricht` LONGTEXT NOT NULL , 
`Datum` DATE NOT NULL , 
FOREIGN KEY (Comment_ID) REFERENCES $tblGuestbookUsr(Usr_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Succes <br />";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn). "<br />";
}
```

Comment: show your connection file

Comment: I think there is a problem with your connection file. Check it properly

Comment: As @MudassarSaiyed said, your error is occurring long before your query executes. That said, your key structure is not consistent. Your Comments table should have its own id (commend_id), and the foreign key (user_id) should be its own column.

Comment: The error "No Database selected" comes only at the 2nd sql statment for the  second table. When I leave the last line of code in the 2nd tbl out. I mean this line: `code`FOREIGN KEY (Comment_ID) REFERENCES $tblGuestbookUsr(Usr_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`code` then the table is successfully created.

Comment: My connection works.